# How to split file into small data chunks using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I am trying to parse a large file by segmenting file into data chunks on the go. Can someone please help me with this as I am not expert at Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Generally node and the underlying OS will do this automatically for you when you read the file via `fs.createReadStream`. Just use that instead `fs.readFile` and the file will be streamed in chunks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to packetize chunks of data according to size say chunks of 1043 KB. How can I divide the stream into discrete chunks of data?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this, https://npmjs.org/package/chunking-streams, then post your attempted code snippet as required by stackoverflow, and see if folks can help you. My suspicion is you think you need to do this but you don't. What protocol are you intending to send this data over?